# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SpecAugment'

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I am trying to implement a project available on GitHub. https://github.com/DemisEom/SpecAugment.

As shown in instructions I am trying to run the code. But I am getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SpecAugment'`. I did `pip3 install SpecAugment` as per written in Readme and It is showing requirement already satisfied. But I am not able to figure out where is the problem.

I am attaching the screenshot. Please help to solve. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a mistake on their github repo. The `spec` in import line should not be in capitals. The example code in their [Readme](https://github.com/DemisEom/SpecAugment) is different.

It should be:

```
from specAugment import spec_augment_tensorflow
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I reproduced this issue:

I use `pip` to install module '`SpecAugment`' in the current environment of VSCode, and it shows that this module cannot be found when it runs.

Solution:

Find the installation package of the module 'SpecAugment' just installed in the current environment directory. We will find that the first letter of the name of the folder `specAugment` is a lowercase letter s. When I change it to `SpecAugment`, it can be imported successfully.

[image]